# Laravel: Missing required parameters (I want to create a product list)

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a Laravel application with shopping cart function. I am following instructions in this website([Create a Shopping Cart with Laravel 6](https://salitha94.blogspot.com/2019/11/create-shopping-cart-with-laravel-6-part-1.html)) with small alteration to match what I want to build.

What I want to do is show a list of products of each store according to the parameter of a url.

example:

https://productlist/1 => show product list of shop1

https://productlist/2 => show product list of shop2

I am trying to do this following the website I mentioned before, and here's the error I got.

> Missing required parameters for [Route: shop] [URI: menu/{user}]. (View: C:\Users\toyop\Desktop\myproject\resources\views\partials\navbar.blade.php)
> http://localhost:8000/menu/1

Since navbar.blade.php is mentioned in the error I thought there's where tha problem is but I couldn't find any parameters in there.

Here are my codes.

**web.php**

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Product;
    use App\Models\User;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class CartController extends Controller
    {
    public function shop($user)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($user);
        return view('shop')->withTitle('E-COMMERCE STORE | SHOP')->with(['user' => $user]);
    }

    public function cart()
    {
        $cartCollection = \Cart::getContent();
        //dd($cartCollection);
        return view('cart')->withTitle('E-COMMERCE STORE | CART')->with(['cartCollection' => $cartCollection]);;
    }

    public function add(Request $request)
    {
        \Cart::add(array(
            'id' => $request->id,
            'name' => $request->name,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'quantity' => $request->quantity,
            'attributes' => array(
                'image' => $request->img,
                'slug' => $request->slug
            )
        ));
        return redirect()->route('cart.index')->with('success_msg', 'Item is Added to Cart!');
    }

    public function remove(Request $request)
    {
        \Cart::remove($request->id);
        return redirect()->route('cart.index')->with('success_msg', 'Item is removed!');
    }

    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        \Cart::update(
            $request->id,
            array(
                'quantity' => array(
                    'relative' => false,
                    'value' => $request->quantity
                ),
            )
        );
        return redirect()->route('cart.index')->with('success_msg', 'Cart is Updated!');
    }

    public function clear()
    {
        \Cart::clear();
        return redirect()->route('cart')->with('success_msg', 'Car is cleared!');
    }
}
```

**show.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app3')

@section('content')
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 80px">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Shop</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <h4>Products In Our Store</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                @foreach($user->products as $pro)
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 20px; height: auto;">
                        <img src="/storage/image/{{$pro->image}}" class="card-img-top mx-auto" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;display: block;" alt="{{ $pro->image }}">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <a href="">
                                <h6 class="card-title">{{ $pro->name }}</h6>
                            </a>
                            <p>${{ $pro->price }}</p>
                            <form action="{{ route('cart.store') }}" method="POST">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{ $pro->id }}" id="id" name="id">
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{ $pro->name }}" id="name" name="name">
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{ $pro->price }}" id="price" name="price">
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{ $pro->image }}" id="img" name="img">
                                <input type="hidden" value="1" id="quantity" name="quantity">
                                <div class="card-footer" style="background-color: white;">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" class="tooltip-test" title="add to cart">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> add to cart
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**navbar.blade.php**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark shadow-sm">
<div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
        E-COMMERCE STORE
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('shop') }}">SHOP</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark">
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> {{ \Cart::getTotalQuantity()}}
                    </span>
                </a>

                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="width: 450px; padding: 0px; border-color: #9DA0A2">
                    <ul class="list-group" style="margin: 20px;">
                        @include('partials.cart-drop')
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated as I have tried multiple methods with no success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `href="{{ route('shop') }}"` requires passing in a user

Comment: Hi aynber,
`Route::get('/menu/{user}', 'CartController@shop')->name('shop');` is not what you mean right? If it's not too much trouble, could you show me how to do that?

Comment: It's the `{user}` part of the route that's missing. You need to pass in the user or the user ID. See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#named-routes

Comment: Hey,
I changed it to `href="{{ url('/menu/{user}') }}"` and now it's working.
Thanks for your help aynber;D